# How to make HDFS folder in windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

For instance to run Spark application in IntellIJ on windows we use winutils.exe (https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems). Then there must be a way how to create a HDFS system on windows. If we could do so then other HDFS systems could be connected (For instance cloudera docker container).

Comment: Yes... You can install Hadoop on windows. What issues are you having? https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 I created question to get more experienced users view on this problem (windows is not good option but my work  laptop is. I prefer Linux). And it is good to experiment on different OS. Thank you for good comment :)

Comment: You need to install Hadoop on Windows to run HDFS filesystem creation commands! Java is cross platform. Windows or Mac doesn't matter. You can also *use Spark* to import the hadoop `FileSystem` object and create directories